# Scheduler for asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Is there a schedule control in asp.net.

What I need:
column display: users
Rows display  : months and days.

On clicking  cell will open a popup

In popup we can : 
  - select a status in a dropdownList, 
  - if the status is "be close" => two calendars ( date start and end) 
  - then apply a color   for the selected period.

I know I would not find an exact need control, but I want a component that would be closest.
Somethink like http://www.daypilot.org/   or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/EventCalendarControl.aspx.

hoping to be clearly understandable.

thank you for your help will be precious to me.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? It's difficult to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Are you wanting something to help someone enter a date, do something on a particular date, or something else?  This is still rather confusing to my mind in terms of what are you wanting and what is adequate background.  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/design/sunny/defaultcs.aspx may be something you want but is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default control for scheduling in ASP.NET, no. The link you provided to Code Project looks pretty nice though, and daypilot.org has an open source version. Would that not work for you?

http://www.daypilot.org/daypilot-lite/

Comment: Kindly update the link from "**http**" to "**https**" (would be better if "**.html**" is truncated

Comment: @MalikAsif I've updated the link to what the *.html* referenced, but the *https* was both not what what the link forwarded to, nor accessible from behind my firewall.